# How to pull up a Gamecenter leaderboard with a button?

Tags: ios, button, leaderboard

I am trying to use the button to pull up a single view Gamecenter leaderboard and cant really figure out how. I tried apples forums but didnt help so I came here. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller that will present the GKGameCenterViewController must conform to the `<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>` protocol.

To present the leaderboard:

```
GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL) {
        leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: How do I implement the "gamecenterViewControllerDidFinish"?

Comment: Implement the method in your view controller's implementation file.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKGameCenterControllerDelegate/gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:

Comment: I would recommend following Apple's Game Center tutorials.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html

Comment: How do I implement the LocalPlayer?

Comment: Apple's leaderboard tutorial walks you through all the steps you need to setup gamecenter in your app. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html  It uses the GameCenterManager class https://github.com/nihalahmed/GameCenterManager